# Amazon SES Templates or Apache Velocity

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, templates, velocity, amazon-ses

I'm building a very simple template email service for sending notification emails. I am currently debating between Amazon Simple Email Service for rendering templates or building my own service using Apache Velocity which sends via SMTP. What are the pros and cons of either?

Amazon SES seems to support both HTML and plain text messages. It also supports templates for the subject line of the email. However, the documentation for the template syntax seems very difficult to find. And managing the templates could be more difficult since they can only be provisioned through their API, CLI, or Terraform.

It would require a bit more work to implement Velocity templates, but the templates would be managed in the same deploy-able as the code and versioned with it. It might also be easier if I wanted to manage templates while the service is running since I could put them in my own data store.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same dilema. Which way have you chosen? What is your experience about it?

Seems own templates solution with custom data store if more future proof if you'd ever need to change email provider. Over wise choosing email provider which has template functionality could be faster to market.

Btw. I haven't found any transactional email provider which support multiple lingual templates so you can `SendTemplatedEmail("reciepient@mail.com", "template_ID", "en-US");` Do you know any?

Comment: I ended up going with Velocity templates and using SES just for the SMTP server. I didn't like the way that templates were managed in SES and couldn't find good documentation around their template syntax.

Comment: I haven't had a need for multi lingual templates. If you are keeping the same format and just changing string you could do that using velocity. Basically add your translation map to the context so your templates could have `$translations.get($whateverString).get($language)`